# Symfony mongo. how search document for name?

Tags: mongodb, symfony, search, service, repository

I have form action for search service

```
<div class="search">
        <form action="{{ path('app_song_search') }}" metod="POST" class="form-search">
            <input type="text" name="search" class="input-medium search-query" />
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Search"/>
        </form>
    </div>
```

DB - Mongo, search for field $name in document song
I create service

```
class Search {
protected $repository;

public function __construct(SongRepository $repository)
{
    $this->repository = $repository;
}

public function search($string)
{
    return $this->repository->getIdArrayByName($string);
}
}
```

and I have action

```
public function searchAction(Request $request)
{
    $searcher = $this->get('searcher');
    $result = $searcher->search($request->get('search'));
    $repository = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getRepository('AppBundle:Song');
    $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('m')
        ->where('m.id IN (:ids)')
        ->setParameter('ids', $result)
        ->getQuery();
    $song = $query->getResult();

    if (!$song){
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Opss, dont search');
    }

    return $this->render('AppBundle::serchSong.html.twig', array('song' => $song));
}
```

and songRepository

```
function getIdArrayByName($name)
{
    return $this->getDocumentManager()->createQueryBuilder($this->findByName($name))
        ->setQueryArray('name', '%'.$name.'%');
}
```

Notice: Undefined offset: 0. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the nameof service? services config please.

Comment: [link](https://github.com/shubaivan/memory/blob/4CreateSearchSong/src/AppBundle/Resources/config/services.xml#L20-L30)